# How to open .sav extension IDL file imageJ?

Tags: imagej, idl

I have a stack of images. These images are the IDL output with the .sav extension. I couldn't find a jar file that supports this in imageJ. How do I open these images in ImageJ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is possible using OME Bio-Formats, with a script:
https://docs.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/5.9.2/users/idl/index.html?highlight=idl

Edit: this link describes how to read images into IDL, the OP was asking for the opposite.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken to read the file in this IDL.  I want the exact opposite. How do I read the IDL file in imageJ?

Comment: You are correct. I will edit my answer. Sorry, I don't know, you might get more responses on https://forum.image.sc